# Handling the order of dropping constraints in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am using a tool called apgdiff 'https://www.apgdiff.com/' for finding the DDL diff between 2 postgres database. It parses 2 postgres dumps and generate the diff between the 2 dumps in terms of alter queries .
       The tool actually doesn't mind the order of creating or dropping  foreign key constraints while generating the diff. i.e. foreign key constraints should be created after primary key , or to be dropped before dropping the primary key . But still, what  makes me curious is a line of code in their sourcecode, which says that all the primary keys should be dropped first and then all other non-primary keys should be dropped . Do we have any such constraint in Postgres that the primary keys should be dropped first and then the remaining constraints ..

Answer (score 1):

If anything, other constraints should be dropped first, because foreign key constraints depend on primary key (or unique) constraints. It doesn't matter, though, if you use the `CASCADE` keyword when dropping the constraints.

I can't see a reason why dropping primary key constraints first should make a difference.

Comment: Do we have any such constraints in older version of POstgres Laurenz...

Comment: Not that I know of.